# Angularjs: how to merge 2 conditions in a ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table where I show items from the database with the ng-repeat. The items are subscriptions which can have weekly or monthly subscription. The table has 3 columns name, weekly and monthly. When a subscription has weekly a tick appear in the cell under the column weekly and if monthly the same. I'm using a ng-if in the td tag like next:

```
<td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
   <span ng-if="engine.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics'" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">

   </span>
</td>
<td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
 <span ng-if="engine.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics'" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">

 </span>
</td>
```

What I would like to reach is that to have that 2 td merged in one with an ng-class, showing the tick under the right column. I would like to do that for make more clean the code if that is possible.

The entire table:

```
<table class="table full-width no-border" ng-if="subscriptionEnginesFromServer.length != 0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="width-240">
                                Engine name
                            </th>
                            <th class="width-240">
                                Weekly
                            </th>
                            <th class="width-240">
                                Monthly
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-show="!loading">
                        <tr ng-repeat="engine in subscriptionEnginesFromServer | orderBy:'name'">
                            <td class="">
                                <!-- clickable-td -->
                                <span class="first-letter-to-upper">
                                    {{engine.name}}
                                </span>
                                <span class="button-icon button--primary button--delete" ng-click="removeEngineFromSubscriptionServer(websites)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
                                <span ng-if="engine.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics'" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">

                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="td-with-button center valign-top">
                                <span ng-if="engine.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics'" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">

                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like?

```
<td colspan="2" ng-class="{
    'class-weekly': engine.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics, 
    'class-monthly': engine.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics
}">
```

Use css to define styles for the classes appropriately.

Comment: Seems nice but I have a question where I put here the icon in this example?
    
   class="fa fa-check"

Comment: Same as your current approach, put a `<span>` inside the cell

Comment: I did in a next way but this not work can you explain what I'm doing wrong, please 

    `<td colspan="2" ng-class="{'class-weekly': engine.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics, 'class-monthly': engine.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics}">
                                    <span ng-if="engine.type == 'WeeklyAnalytics'" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span ng-if="engine.type == 'MonthlyAnalytics'" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </td>`

Comment: I discovered it is not possible in the way I want because I should preserve the table structure